# Como limitar os resultados no Oracle sem ler a tabela inteira?

Tags: oracle

Como eu posso retornar as 100 primeiras linhas de uma tabela sem precisar ler todos seus registros?

Minha tabela tem 4milhoes de linhas , e eu estou tendo problemas ao tentar retornar apenas suas 100 primeiras linhas, porque toda vez que eu uso o ROWNUM, o sgbd lê toda a tabela (eu acho, já que demora horas para terminar a query).

Exemplo:

```
SELECT ACCT FROM ACCT_CUST AC WHERE AC.TYPE != "DT" AND ROWNUM < 100;
```

Oracle não tem TOP ou Limit, então eu não sei como usar o rownum para pegar as linhas sem ler a tabela inteira

Comment: O Rownum funciona igual ao TOP ou LIMIT, a unica diferença é a sintaxe. Mas este comportamento indica que você não tem um indice pela coluna TYPE . Se tiver um indice neste coluna, pode tentar forçar utiliza-lo através da diretiva choose.

Answer (score 2):

1- Seja especifico na sua busca;

```
SELECT ACCT FROM ACCT_CUST AC WHERE AC.TYPE IN ("AA","BB")
```

Usando clausula `!=` você obriga o `index` a comparar todos os resultados diferentes do seu resultado.

2- Para melhorar a performance do seu resultado;

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT AC.ACCT, RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY AC.TYPE ) LINHA 
FROM ACCT_CUST AC 
WHERE AC.TYPE IN ("AA","BB","CC")
 )aux WHERE aux.LINHA BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Para mais veja na documentação da oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm